# No sorting is applied on the list. Create user not coming as first record

Tags: user-record, user-admin

1. Login to salesforce with  admin .
2. Go to manage users .
3. click on manage users .
4. Create a user from new user button.

Expected Result:
After creating the user should show as first record. The list should be sorted by created date.

Actual Result:
No sorting is applied on the list. Create user not coming as first record.

Comment: Are you reporting a salesforce bug?

Answer (score 1):

The sorting to the users related list will be whatever sorting the admin had when they came to the page.  You can create a new View or edit the existing one to add in the Created Date to make it available for sorting. If the admin then chooses to sort by Created Date ascending by clicking on the column header, they will see the most recently created users at the top of the list.  See the help document, [Sorting List Views](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=basics_sorting_list_views.htm&language=en_US).

Here is an example that shows it.  Note the down arrow on the Created Date column showing that the users are sorted by Created Date.  Also, note the Edit and Create New View links.  Click those to edit or create a new View. You can create a View that is shared with all users or specific users if need be. See [Creating Custom List Views](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customviews.htm&language=en_US) for more information.
[image: Manage Users list view showing sorting]

There is one other possibility. If the organization has more than 2 million users, the users list view cannot be sorted according to [this help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=basics_sorting_list_views.htm&language=en_US):

> Starting in Spring ‘13, list views for the Users object in organizations that have more than two million users cannot be sorted.

Comment: modifying question:

Comment: 1.Login to salesforce with admin .
2. Go to manage users tab from '+' .
3. click on manage users tab.
4. Create a user from new user button.
Expected Result:
After creating the user should show as first record. The list should be sorted by created date.
Actual Result:
No sorting is applied on the list. Create user not coming as first record.      We are using VF page.

Comment: @user10584 - What column was the list view sorted by when the New User button was clicked?  That's what I would expect it to sort by.

Comment: </apex:column>
          <apex:column onclick="this.setAttribute('onchange','SetModified(true)')">
            <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.User.fields.Username.label}</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!user.userName}"/>
          </apex:column>

Comment: sort by created date.

Comment: newly created user come on top

Comment: @user10584 - It appears that you posted a code snippet in the comment. It would be best to include the code that is not working in your question and make it clear that your question is about code (Visualforce and Apex). Currently, your question is about the standard admin screen which is why I answered how I did.

Comment: query='Select Id, Name, UserName, CommunityNickName, Email, Profile.Name, Contact.Account.Name, IsActive, LastLoginDate From User Where ContactId!=null And Profile.UserLicense.Name like \'%Community%\' And Profile.Description like \'%Community%\' ' + query + 'And Contact.Account.Id=\'' + targetAccountId + '\' Order By Name';